# Basement wall framing - Attaching top plate with pipes in the way

Tags: basement, framing, ducts

I'm laying out framing for a basement wall and currently stuck on how to attach the top track.

The problem is there is a good sized heat pipe running parallel between two joists (the other ductwork I'm just going to run underneath). So I don't have enough room to attach the top track directly to the joist and I also can't attach wood blocking between the joists either. See image for reference.
[image]

[image]

My only idea was to screw in short 2x4 pieces to the joist vertically, in-between the obstructions, and attach the top plate to each verical piece, spaced out every 3 ft or so. But I've read that attaching things to joists like this transfers load from the floor/joists to the wall which I want to avoid.

Anyone have any ideas?

Edit* example 2x4
[image]

Comment: Exactly where is the wall suppose to go?  The top plate mainly holds the wall from tipping over, so if most of it is attached to the joists and a section is shorter(with short studs) to past the pipes, it should work.  Two end sections to the joists, and where the pipes are, shorten the studs and have the short top plate attached to longer studs/jack studs(like a door/window).

Comment: To try and maximize space, the exterior wall would be flush with the end of the ductwork. Id like to avoid brining the wall in anymore.

Comment: Why can't you connect directly to the joist? You just need to get one (or two) studs up to the joist in the tight spot from your image. Then your top plate butts into the face of that stud and another full height stud at the other end of all of the obstructions.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is.  You're gonna have to build a chase for the ducts, which is commonly done.  This isn't gonna be a load-bearing wall, so you don't even necessarily need a top plate along the entire length.

Answer (score 1):

Nonbearing walls commonly pick up loading from the floor. It's actually kind of a nice feature. When you walk on an upper floor, part of the load gets redistributed to the lower floor.

The worrying part of your detail is the *eccentric* loading that you would be applying to the floor joists when the floor deflects. This is not the well-centered loading that floor joists are designed to carry. Blocking between joists at the eccentrically loaded position is the typical solution to allow for your loads. Obviously this is infeasible based on your description of the problem.

Instead, just opportunistically attach studs to the bottom of the joist whenever you can. Install a little chunk of top plate for these studs instead of fastening the studs directly to the joist. These top plate chunks face nail nicely to the joists so you don't have to cram a bunch of toe nails in the tiny little 1-1/2"x1-1/2" bearing area. Between the resulting floor-to-floor studs, install the top plate for sections of wall that end short of the upper floor.